# Problem with tick not showing on a plot made with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am working on the creation of a number of industrial fatigue plots, but on the MWE, the tick and tick label "C" does not appear, and I do not know why and how to correct this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.5.1}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
title= {Fatigue test results per configuration.},
y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            1000 sep={\thinspace},
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
   only marks,enlargelimits=0.15, 
   xlabel={Configuration style},ylabel={Cycles before failure}, 
   symbolic x coords={A,C}, xtick=data,]
\addplot coordinates {(A,1362)(A,2840) (A,687)(A,2771)};
\addplot coordinates {(C,2130)(C,3544) (C,1844)(C,3447)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xtick=data` only uses the first `\addplot` command for determining the tick positions. You should use `xtick={A,C}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.5.1}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
title= {Fatigue test results per configuration.},
y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            1000 sep={\thinspace},
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
   only marks,enlargelimits=0.15, 
   xlabel={Configuration style},ylabel={Cycles before failure}, 
   symbolic x coords={A,C}, xtick={A,C}]
\addplot coordinates {(A,1362)(A,2840) (A,687)
(A,2771)};
\addplot coordinates {(C,2130)(C,3544) (C,1844)(C,3447)}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```